# About the past perfect and its proper use is a sentence

Tags: grammar, past-perfect

When they had celebrated their 50 anniversary, it was already popular.

Is this sentence correct?  (I Think it must be just the other way around?)

Comment: *What* was already popular?

Comment: A family reunion

Comment: Your sentence doesn't seem to make sense. If you are talking about a 50th anniversary party, how can it have been 'already popular'? If you mean that a lot of people wanted to attend, that can only have happened _after_ the party was announced. You could say "When they had celebrated their 50th anniversary, it had been a great success".

Comment: One way to express what I think you mean is: _Reunions were already popular in their family when they celebrated their 50th anniversary_. You don't need the past perfect here.

Comment: This is a terrible sentence if it stands alone, for the reasons given in the comments, and 50 should indeed be 50th.  But sometimes native English speakers do reverse the past and the past perfect in this way (although maybe not in this sentence). To say whether it's correct, we would have to see the previous sentences.

Answer (score -1):

Proper sentence:
Family reunion had already been popular when they celebrated their 50th anniversary.

1. "50" must be "50th"
2. It does not matter if it is in another way round, "When they celebrated their 50th anniversary, family reunion had already been popular." is okay.
3. You should give the information(a family reunion or a wedding party) about what "it" is. And you should give information about what 50th anniversary they are having if you are making sentences.
4. It should be "family reunion had already been popular" because family reunion had been popular ***before*** "they" celebrated their 50th anniversary.
5. It should be "when they celebrated their 50th anniversary" because they celebrated their 50th anniversary ***after*** family reunion had been popular.

Comment: First, native speakers of English sometimes really do reverse past perfect and past in the way the OP is confused about. Second, you can't use the verb *be* in the past perfect with *already* the way you do. You have to say *Family reunions had already **become** popular* or *already **were** popular* or ***had been** popular for a long time*.